# jquery supersized with navigation bar beneath

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to incoporate a homepage using the jquery supersized plugin to display a slideshow that fills the page with the image, with the exception of a navigation bar at the bottom of the page.

The navigation bar is 110px high with a width of 100%. The problem I am having is getting the images to "stop" at 110pixels from the bottom of the page. I have played around with the supersized css file I downloaded with the plugin but nothing seems to be doing the trick.

Does anyone know if it is possible, or whether there are any other full screen slideshows I might be able to use that will allow for a space at the bottom of the page?

Thanks
JD

Comment: Maybe show us some code? something? so that we can help you? try making a jsfiddle.net example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't only modify the CSS.**

You need  to understand how this plugin work.

**First**, it create a div at the bottom of your page. This div got the following CSS :

```
#supersized {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

This style make it the size of your screen and put it under all other content.

**Second**, inside that div, you have an `IMG`.
This image have the following style :

```
#supersized img {
    border: medium none;
    height: auto;
    image-rendering: optimizequality;
    outline: medium none;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

**However**, part of this style is ***Overwritten by the plugin!***

```
<img src="img.jpg" style="width: 1672.22px; left: -4px; top: 0px; height: 602px;" />
```

And this style is defined in the **plugin JS core**.

If you want to make your picture 110px less high than what the plugin do, you'll have to also change the following line (**supersized.3.1.3.core.js, line 84**):

```
//Gather browser size
var browserwidth = $(window).width();
var browserheight = $(window).height();
var offset;
```

...Which is rather hard are if you are using the minified version.

**Other suggestion** : [Look at the supersized demo(http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html) and do a similar navigation bar (transparent!), or allow the user to hide the navigation bar (hide it in a corner) if they really want the 110px.

Answer (score 0):

```
#controls-wrapper {
  bottom:100px !important;
}
#supersized li {
  bottom:100px !important;
  height:auto !important;
}
```

Try that?

Comment: tried, doesn't work. This will cover the image from the bottom. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12240999/300248

Comment: I thought I had tested that.  The image adjusts to the new size.  You might have to change the second css selector to `#supersized, #supersized li` instead.  Do you have a fiddle or jsbin set up?