# How to take 100px from a Supersized fullscreen slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A [Supersized slideshow](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html) stretches slideshow images to fill the screen. Yet I would like to have a 100px header before the slideshow (not over it). How can I do?

[The FAQ explains that the slideshow needs not to be fullscreen](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/faq.html#q-3), yet I still want it to be fullscreen, expect for 100px from the top.

Comment: Hello people who downvote: would you care to EXPLAIN why you do so to OP (and ask for closing the question if needed)?

Comment: doesn't that FAQ explain exactly what needs to be done?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a bit since you've asked, but I've used this to shrink the space that Supersized takes up.

```
function portfolioSize () {
    $('#supersized').height( $(window).height() - 71 );
}
$(window).load(function() { portfolioSize(); });
$(window).resize(function() { portfolioSize(); });
```

This pulls the window height and subtracts the necessary amount of pixels. The two lines below serve to ensure the function is applied on initial load and when the browser window is resized.

EDIT: As a side note, I believe the following CSS may be required as well (It's been a bit since I've worked on the site that needed this, so these could be there for other reasons):

```
#supersized {position: relative !important;}

#supersized li {position: absolute !important; height: 100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy - just add this to the CSS:

```
#supersized li {top:100px !important}
```

Then use absolute positioning to add your header to the top of the screen :)

Comment: this way you just cover the top 100px but Supersized still stretches the full screen. So the top 100px of the slide are covered.

Comment: No, that's not right. When I add 100px to the li, the whole picture moves down 100px.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. So the *bottom* 100px of the slide are covered by the navigation tray

Comment: Right, so you don't want it full screen at all - you want the image to stretch to the biggest size it can, while still being inside the window?

Comment: yes, I want the image to stretch to the biggest size it can, while still being inside the window not stretching over the top 100px nor bottom

Comment: Maybe you need to find a different script, then, because that's not a CSS thing, it's the function that the JS is using. Try asking your question again, but rather than focusing on the top margin, ask about how to make the slideshow NOT be full screen, instead fit the image inside the page (or available space).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a container or `div` with `display: block` and `margin-top: 100px` and set your slideshow inside that. Or you may simply try assigning a `margin-top: 100px` or `top: 100px` to your slideshow parent selector. (that is, you may giv this to `ul` if u use `li` or some parent container of slideshow).

You may even try a `padding-top` or `border-top` and assign them 100px. You have a lot of choices.

I recommend you to use a fluidic layout. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/kvHWm/)*** is a Live Demo.

Comment: the problem with all the options you suggested, as with zenktaty's, is that Supersized will still stretche the full screen. So the top 100px of the slide become covered.